# Golang: Why does response.Get("headerkey") not return a value in this code?

Tags: http, curl, go, header

This has been bothering me for the past couple hours, I'm trying to get a response header value. Simple stuff. If I `curl` a request to this running server, I see the header set, with curl's `-v` flag, but when I try to retrieve the header using Go's `response.Header.Get()`, it shows a blank string `""`, with the header's length being 0.

What frustrates me even more, is that the header value is actually set within the response when I print out the body (as demonstrated below).

Any and all help with this is appreciated, thanks in advance.

I have this code here:
http://play.golang.org/p/JaYTfVoDsq

Which contains the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    server := httptest.NewServer(mux)
    defer server.Close()

    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        r.Header.Set("Authorization", "responseAuthVal")
        fmt.Fprintln(w, r.Header)
    })

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", server.URL, nil)
    res, _:= http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    headerVal := res.Header.Get("Authorization")

    fmt.Printf("auth header=%s, with length=%d\n", headerVal, len(headerVal))
    content, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    fmt.Printf("res.Body=%s", content)
    res.Body.Close()
}
```

The output to this running code is:

```
auth header=, with length=0
res.Body=map[Authorization:[responseAuthVal] User-Agent:[Go-http-client/1.1] Accept-Encoding:[gzip]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
        r.Header.Set("Authorization", "responseAuthVal")
```

set the value of `r *http.Request`, that is the incomming request, while you want to set the value of `w http.ResponseWriter`, the response that you will receive.

The said line should be

```
        w.Header().Set("Authorization", "responseAuthVal")
```

See [this](http://play.golang.org/p/yuX50FEilG) playgroud.